# Mapping @OnetoOne on composite key column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

Firstly i have two Entities Folder and FolderObjectID with their corresponding tables.

On Folder Table i have composite key FolderID and ParentFolderID

```
Table Folder
+----------------+ 
|    Folder      |
+----------------+
|#FolderID       |
|#ParentFolderID |
+----------------+
```

On FolderObjectID table i have FolderObjectID as primary key.

```
Table FolderObjectID
+----------------+
| FolderObjectID |
+----------------+
|#FolderObjectID |
+----------------+
```

Folder Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Folder")
public class Folder implements java.io.Serializable {

   private FolderId id;

   //setter getter
}
```

Embeddable class

```
@Embeddable
public class FolderId implements java.io.Serializable {

  private Integer folderId;
  private Integer parentFolderId;

  //setter getter
}
```

FolderObjectID Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FolderObjectID")
public class FolderObjectID implements java.io.Serializable {

   private folderObjectId id;

   //setter getter
}
```

Now what i wanted to have is a one to one relationship on the two entity using FolderID column of Folder table to link on FolderObjectID column of FolderObjectID table. Unfortunately I'm getting error saying i have a broken column on Folder entity.

Can somebody enlighten me on this matter.
Thanks.

Comment: What's the primary key in FolderObjectID table? As per your description it should be folderId. So correct that first and then repost the table structure and Entity.

Comment: FolderObjectID is the primary key. i have folderObjectId as property for it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `@MapsId` feature I guess.
Similar to this but I haven't tried it yet:

Folder Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Folder")
public class Folder implements java.io.Serializable {

   @EmbeddedId
   private FolderId id;

   @OneToOne
   @MapsId("folderId")
   private FolderObject folderObject;
}
```

FolderObjectID Entity

```
@Entity @Table(name = "FolderObjectID")
public class FolderObjectID implements java.io.Serializable {

   @Id
   private long folderObjectId;

   @OneToOne(mappedBy = "folderObject")
   @JoinColumn(name = "folderObjectId") 
   private Folder folder;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the @MapsId is not available. I think im using a lower version.